# Automatically Add Next Value (+1) to TAG POS=(number) for iMacro?

Tags: imacros

I'm creating an iMacro to update wordpress posts. I have the following:

```
    URL GOTO=https://www.example.com
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
    WAIT SECONDS=2
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
    WAIT SECONDS=2
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
    WAIT SECONDS=2
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
    WAIT SECONDS=4
    TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
    WAIT SECONDS=2
```

The problem I have is that I need to update 400+ pages/posts.

The code:
        TAG POS=NUMBER TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit

tells which post to update, so I know I have to make POS=2, POS=3, POS=4, etc. all the way up to 400 but I need a better way, instead of copy pasting and manually editing each line.

Is there a way to make the code say TAG POS=N+1 or something to make it the next number until it reaches 400?

This is an example of 1-10

```
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=4 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=5 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=6 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=7 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=8 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=9 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=10 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

There has to be a better way to doing this up to 400? :(

Comment: Sure, the best way is to use the `!LOOP` variable and play the macro in loop mode.

Answer (score 1):

I will translate Shugar's answer to code:

```
URL GOTO=https://www.example.com
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Edit
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Map
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:post ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Check
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:post ATTR=ID:publish
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Previous
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

All we did is change the position to `{{!LOOP}}` at line 2 and if you run it as "Play (Loop)" with max = 400 it will solve your issue. If something broke and you want to start from pos X lets say 200 you can set the !LOOP to start from that number